# Circling around some text

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

I would like to be able to draw a line around some expression.
So far, I have found how to draw a circle around an expression, but I wonder if it is possible to **draw a less restrictive shape** (ellipse, rounded rectangle, any kind of closed curve with a good regularity).

## What I did so far

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}


% ---------------------------------------- %
% 15/05/19 %
\def\dsp{\displaystyle}
\def\ssk{\smallskip}

\def\Objet{\textrm{Objet}}
\def\Prop{\textrm{Prop}}

\newcommand{\gives}[2]{\left. \begin{array}{l} #1\end{array}\right | \!\! \raisebox{1mm}{\rule{2ex}{0.4pt}}\ #2}

% ---------------------------------------- %
\makeatletter
\newcommand\mathcircled[1]{%
  \mathpalette\@mathcircled{#1}%
}
\newcommand\@mathcircled[2]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(math.base)] \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt] (math) {$\m@th#1#2$};%
}
\makeatother
% ---------------------------------------- %

\newcommand{\ofType}{\,{\boldsymbol{:}}\,}

% ---------------------------------------- %


\begin{document}

\subsection*{Objets}

\begin{enumerate}[1., font = \bfseries]
\item \ \\
$\gives{x\ofType\Objet \\ y\ofType\Objet}{\mathcircled{x,y}\ofType\Objet}$

\item[1'.] \ \\
$\gives{x\ofType\Objet \\ y\ofType\Objet}{\mathcircled{\Pi(x,y)}\ofType\Objet}$

\item[1''.] \ \\
$\gives{A\ofType\Objet \\ X\ofType\mathcircled{A\to{}\Objet}}{\mathcircled{\dsp\prod_{a:A}X(a)}\ofType\Objet}$


\item \ \\
$\gives{x\ofType\Objet \\ y\ofType\Objet}{\mathcircled{x\to{}y}\ofType\Objet}$

\item \ \\
$\gives{
x\ofType X \\ 
f\ofType\mathcircled{X\to{}Y}}{f(x)\ofType Y}$

\item \ \\
$\gives{
f\ofType\mathcircled{X\to{}Y} \\
g\ofType\mathcircled{Y\to{}Z}}{\mathcircled{g\circ f}\ofType \mathcircled{X\to{}Z}}$

\item \ \\
$\gives{
x\ofType\Objet \\ 
y\ofType\Objet}{\mathcircled{x=y}\ofType \Prop}$


\item \ \\
$\gives{
x\ofType X \\ 
f\ofType\mathcircled{X\to{}Y} \\
g\ofType\mathcircled{Y\to{}Z}}{\textrm{def}_{g \circ f, x}\ofType\mathcircled{\mathcircled{g\circ f}(x) = g(f(x))}}$

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## What I would like to draw

Here is something looking like what I would like to draw.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose whatever you prefer.

#### Ellipse

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}


% ---------------------------------------- %
% 15/05/19 %
\def\dsp{\displaystyle}
\def\ssk{\smallskip}

\def\Objet{\textrm{Objet}}
\def\Prop{\textrm{Prop}}

\newcommand{\gives}[2]{\left. \begin{array}{l} #1\end{array}\right | \!\! \raisebox{1mm}{\rule{2ex}{0.4pt}}\ #2}

% ---------------------------------------- %
\makeatletter
\newcommand\mathcircled[1]{%
  \mathpalette\@mathcircled{#1}%
}
\newcommand\@mathcircled[2]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(math.base)] {
    \node[draw,ellipse,inner sep=1pt] (math) {$\m@th#1#2$};
    \path ([yshift=-1pt]math.south);
    \path ([yshift=1pt]math.north);
  }%
}
\makeatother
% ---------------------------------------- %

\newcommand{\ofType}{\,{\boldsymbol{:}}\,}

% ---------------------------------------- %


\begin{document}

\subsection*{Objets}

\begin{enumerate}[1., font = \bfseries]
\item \ \\
$\gives{x\ofType\Objet \\ y\ofType\Objet}{\mathcircled{x,y}\ofType\Objet}$

\item[1'.] \ \\
$\gives{x\ofType\Objet \\ y\ofType\Objet}{\mathcircled{\Pi(x,y)}\ofType\Objet}$

\item[1''.] \ \\
$\gives{A\ofType\Objet \\ X\ofType\mathcircled{A\to{}\Objet}}{\mathcircled{\dsp\prod_{a:A}X(a)}\ofType\Objet}$


\item \ \\
$\gives{x\ofType\Objet \\ y\ofType\Objet}{\mathcircled{x\to{}y}\ofType\Objet}$

\item \ \\
$\gives{
x\ofType X \\ 
f\ofType\mathcircled{X\to{}Y}}{f(x)\ofType Y}$

\item \ \\
$\gives{
f\ofType\mathcircled{X\to{}Y} \\
g\ofType\mathcircled{Y\to{}Z}}{\mathcircled{g\circ f}\ofType \mathcircled{X\to{}Z}}$

\item \ \\
$\gives{
x\ofType\Objet \\ 
y\ofType\Objet}{\mathcircled{x=y}\ofType \Prop}$


\item \ \\
$\gives{
x\ofType X \\ 
f\ofType\mathcircled{X\to{}Y} \\
g\ofType\mathcircled{Y\to{}Z}}{\textrm{def}_{g \circ f, x}\ofType\mathcircled{\mathcircled{g\circ f}(x) = g(f(x))}}$

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

#### Rounded rectangle

I have to increase `inner sep`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}


% ---------------------------------------- %
% 15/05/19 %
\def\dsp{\displaystyle}
\def\ssk{\smallskip}

\def\Objet{\textrm{Objet}}
\def\Prop{\textrm{Prop}}

\newcommand{\gives}[2]{\left. \begin{array}{l} #1\end{array}\right | \!\! \raisebox{1mm}{\rule{2ex}{0.4pt}}\ #2}

% ---------------------------------------- %
\makeatletter
\newcommand\mathcircled[1]{%
  \mathpalette\@mathcircled{#1}%
}
\newcommand\@mathcircled[2]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(math.base)] {
    \node[draw,rounded corners,inner sep=3pt] (math) {$\m@th#1#2$};%
    \path ([yshift=-1.5pt]math.south);
    \path ([yshift=1.5pt]math.south);
  }
}
\makeatother
% ---------------------------------------- %

\newcommand{\ofType}{\,{\boldsymbol{:}}\,}

% ---------------------------------------- %


\begin{document}

\subsection*{Objets}

\begin{enumerate}[1., font = \bfseries]
\item \ \\
$\gives{x\ofType\Objet \\ y\ofType\Objet}{\mathcircled{x,y}\ofType\Objet}$

\item[1'.] \ \\
$\gives{x\ofType\Objet \\ y\ofType\Objet}{\mathcircled{\Pi(x,y)}\ofType\Objet}$

\item[1''.] \ \\
$\gives{A\ofType\Objet \\ X\ofType\mathcircled{A\to{}\Objet}}{\mathcircled{\dsp\prod_{a:A}X(a)}\ofType\Objet}$


\item \ \\
$\gives{x\ofType\Objet \\ y\ofType\Objet}{\mathcircled{x\to{}y}\ofType\Objet}$

\item \ \\
$\gives{
x\ofType X \\ 
f\ofType\mathcircled{X\to{}Y}}{f(x)\ofType Y}$

\item \ \\
$\gives{
f\ofType\mathcircled{X\to{}Y} \\
g\ofType\mathcircled{Y\to{}Z}}{\mathcircled{g\circ f}\ofType \mathcircled{X\to{}Z}}$

\item \ \\
$\gives{
x\ofType\Objet \\ 
y\ofType\Objet}{\mathcircled{x=y}\ofType \Prop}$


\item \ \\
$\gives{
x\ofType X \\ 
f\ofType\mathcircled{X\to{}Y} \\
g\ofType\mathcircled{Y\to{}Z}}{\textrm{def}_{g \circ f, x}\ofType\mathcircled{\mathcircled{g\circ f}(x) = g(f(x))}}$

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you look at items 5 and 6 of the list above, the two frames touch each other. That's the only "small problem" I can see now.

Comment: @Colas Manually increase the spacing using `\\[x]` for example.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'll do or think of a more generic solution that always include a small space above or below the frame.

Comment: @Colas The boxes are now at least 3pt apart.